# Don't understand the result of Promise API

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to get my head around the Promise API, and struggling.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
const myPromise = () => {
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      var name = 'John'
      if (name === 'John') {
         resolve(name)
      }
      else reject('Anonymous')
   })
}
```

Then when I `console.log(myPromise())`, I get...

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "John"}
```

I would expect to get `John` back from this. As it stands, I don't know how to handle the data. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you can't block a call in javascript.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you explain?

Comment: meaning once you go async, you can't go back.

Comment: 'Go back'? Sorry this is all new territory for me, would appreciate if you can give a bit more detail?

Comment: a promise represents the *eventual* result of an async operation, not the result itself.

Comment: You have to wait for the response, right? You wanna do something like `myFunc().then(successFunction(response){ // do stuff}, errorFunction(err){// do stuff})`

Comment: You want `myPromise.then(console.log)`. Returning a promise from a function will return a promise object, not make the function magically wait until the promise settles.